# How to get Xcode to find callers of method if used in a @selector()?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

**Simple method definition:**

```c
-(void)coolMethod {
    // cool method stuff
}
```

**Somewhere else I call the method using a `@selector()`:**

```c
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(coolMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:false];
[timer fire];
```

If I Command+click on `coolMethod` and select `Callers...`, or use the `Navigate to Related Items` menu Xcode doesn't find this usage.

Using AppCode if I do a right-click on `coolMethod` and select `Find Usages` it will find this usage correctly.

How do I get Xcode to find all usages of a method, even ones called in a `@selector()`?

Comment: Your only option is to do a global search for `coolMethod` or `@selector(coolMethod)`.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in `coolMethod` and run the app in the debugger.